# Panda multiply dataframes using dictionary to map columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to multiply element-wise two dataframes with matching indices, using a dictionary to map which columns to multiply together. I can only come up with convoluted ways to do it and I am sure there is a better way, really appreciate the help! thx!

df1:

| Index | ABC | DEF | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2004 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 05/01/2004 | 4 | 7 | 2 |

df2:

| Index | Echo | Epsilon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2004 | 5 | 10 |
| 05/01/2004 | -1 | -2 |

Dictionary `d = {'ABC': 'Echo', 'DEF': 'Echo', 'XYZ': 'Epsilon'}`

Expected result:

| Index | ABC | DEF | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2004 | 5 | 10 | 30 |
| 05/01/2004 | -4 | -7 | -4 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# only if not already the index 
df1 = df1.set_index('Index')
df2 = df2.set_index('Index')

df1.mul(df2[df1.columns.map(d)].set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1))
```

or:

```
df1.mul(df2.loc[df1.index, df1.columns.map(d)].values)
```

output:

```
            ABC  DEF  XYZ
Index                    
01/01/2004    5   10   30
05/01/2004   -4   -7   -4
```